# How do I programmatically scroll a D3 SVG tree sitting inside a flex box div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have a D3 tree with a large SVG area sitting inside a flex box with "overflow:auto" allowing the user to pan/scroll the tree. The nodes of the tree are in a list in a div to the left. When I click the list I d3.select("[id='" + nodeName + "']") and have a valid D3 selection.

How can I programmatically scroll to bring the node into the center of it's container? I'm not sure if this is an HTML/DOM thing or a D3 thing or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave this an a possible answer but it's a bit of a hack...

```
    var y = node.__data__.x;
    var x = node.__data__.y;
    var contentElement = $("#content-area").get(0);
    var clientWidth = contentElement.clientWidth;
    var clientHeight = contentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrollWidth = contentElement.scrollWidth;
    var scrollHeight = contentElement.scrollHeight;
    var scrollX = ((x/svgWidth) * scrollWidth) - (clientWidth/2) ;
    var scrollY = ((y/svgHeight) * scrollHeight) - (clientHeight/2);
    $("#content-area").scrollLeft(scrollX);
    $("#content-area").scrollTop(scrollY);
```

It gets the job done. Some caveats, if your units not translatable to pixels, your have transformations on your elements or your zoomed/translated already this won't work. Also should do clamping, etc. but browser seems to not choke on it :-)

Basically it's a simple pixel to pixel scroll window over the SVG canvas.

Answer (score 0):

So you can put a listener on the click, like so:

```
d3.select(element).on('click', function(d) {
    centerNode(d);
});
```

Then you can define your centerNode function as per example:

```
function centerNode(source) {
    var x = -source.y0 / 2;
    d3.select('g').transition()
        .duration(400)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + 0 + ')');
}
```

That will at least center horizontally. If you want to also center vertically you will have to use the source.x0 property and use that as the second parameter of the translate function.

Comment: The element I'm clicking on isn't a D3 node, it's a simple text list. I then do a d3.select using the list item's name and get the d3 node. So I have a d3 node, and I know it's x/y coordinates, my question is how do I now calculate the correct scroll position so I can set the scrollTop and scrollLeft such that it positions the element in the center?